# DEVISE: Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Sender syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting an error, `Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Sender syntax error`, when attempting to sending registration or password reset emails using Devise.

#### Example From

```
'"Someone" <someone@mysite.com>'
```

#### Mailer

```
class CustomDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include Roadie::Rails::Automatic

  layout 'email'

  default from: '"My Site" <me@mysite.com>'

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    check_white_label record, opts
    super
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    check_white_label record, opts
    super
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
    check_white_label record, opts
    super
  end

  def password_change(record, opts = {})
    check_white_label record, opts
    super
  end

  def check_white_label(record, opts)
    if white_label = record.player&.property&.management&.white_label_name
      opts[:from] = "#{white_label} <#{white_label}@mysite.com>"
      opts[:reply_to] = "#{white_label} <#{white_label}@mysite.com>"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct format for sender email:
`"Someone" <someone@mysite.com>`

Comment: Good catch, that was a typo in my question

Comment: Still having the problem? If so can you update with your mailer config?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by removing the double quotes.

```
def check_white_label(record, opts)
  if white_label = record.player&.property&.management&.white_label_name&.delete('"')
    opts[:from] = "#{white_label} <#{white_label}@mysite.com>"
    opts[:reply_to] = "#{white_label} <#{white_label}@mysite.com>"
end
```

#### output

```
'Someone <someone@mysite.com>'
```